Google Drive API 'drives.list' returning error 400 'invalid query'
I am trying to use a service account to view and access Shared Drives using the Google API.
I using PHP with the google/apiclient version v2.16.0 library to access the API.
Here is my code example:
$client = new \Google\Client();
$client->setApplicationName('My App');
$client->setAuthConfig(<contents of $jsonKey file>);
$client->setScopes([
    \Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE,
    \Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE_APPDATA,
    \Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
    \Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE_METADATA
]);

$service = new \Google\Service\Drive($client);
$optParams = [
  'useDomainAdminAccess' => true,
  'q' => 'name contains Clients',
];

$result1 = $service->drives->listDrives();
$result2 = $service->drives->listDrives($optParams);

$result1 returns the following:
Google\Service\Drive\DriveList Object
(
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [collection_key:protected] => drives
    [drivesType:protected] => Google\Service\Drive\Drive
    [drivesDataType:protected] => array
    [kind] => drive#driveList
    [nextPageToken] => 
    [drives] => Array
        (
        )

)

The list empty since this is a service account, but confirms that authentication is working properly.
$result2 returns an error:
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid Value",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Value",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid",
        "location": "q",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}

I have tried many different types of strings for the 'q' parameter, but I always get an invalid value.  I have also tried omitting the query parameter and just passing the useDomainAdminAccess parameter, but that returns the same error.
Despite many hours of searching I cannot figure out why I am getting this error.
Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for replying. About thank you for your response. I had already tried the query with quotes and double-quotes but was getting the same error., I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't notice that you had already tested my proposed script before I posted it. In this case, my answer was not useful for your situation. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

I discovered that the error was originating due to mismatch in scopes given to the Service Account and set in the Client.
The Service Account scopes enabled in the Admin Console had only the following permission:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
which in PHP Library is equivalent to
\Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE
When I removed the other scopes, the query function worked as documented.
Seems that the Google API and/or PHP Client Library do not generate the proper error message when there is a scope mismatch. Instead, the Invalid value error caused a lot of wasted hours on research and troubleshooting.
